# How to get the maximum row_number() for each group in hive sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Using the row_number() in the hive SQL I can filter the duplicates/pick the first instance of an id by selecting 1 in the where clause as below. What I need here is how can I find the last instance in each group.

```
select * from 
(select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,id, row_number() over(partition by id ORDER BY id) as seq
from 
table) as cnt where seq = 1;
```

My requirement is, for example, if the id 1212 has 3 instances and 1313 has 5 instances in the table something like below, I can use the above query and get only one instance by selecting 1 in the where clause. But I want 3 for the id 1212 and 5 for the id 1313 in the below.

```
 c1,  c2,  c3,  c4,  c5,  ID     seq
2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 1212     1
2021 2020 2021 2020 2021 1212     2
2022 2020 2022 2020 2022 1212     3
2023 2020 2023 2020 2023 1313     1
2024 2020 2024 2020 2024 1313     2
2025 2020 2025 2020 2025 1313     3
2026 2020 2026 2020 2026 1313     4
2026 2020 2026 2020 2026 1313     5
```

Comment: Are there some other columns you are getting and thats why you need rownumber? Otherwise you could just use group by and count.

Comment: I'm getting other columns too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id,max(seq) over(partition by id ORDER BY id)from 
(select *, row_number() over(partition by id ORDER BY id) as seq
from 
table)maxseq
group by id
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm selecting other columns too, I edited my query in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra column with `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cnt`.  That will contain the number of rows in the group which is also the maximum ROW_NUMBER value for the group as well.

Comment: select * from 
(select id, row_number() over(partition by id ORDER BY id ASC) as seq,
COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cnt
from 
table) as cnt where seq = 1; This query dint work. getting this error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException: Argument expected

Comment: Sorry, try `COUNT(*)` instead of just `COUNT()`.  It may not hurt to rename your subquery to something other than `cnt` as that's already a column name.

Answer (score 1):

Use all those columns in the `group by` and use `max` on the `row_number()`

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,id,max(r_no) 
from 
(
    select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,id, row_number() over (partition by id ORDER BY c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,id) as r_no
    from 
    table
) a
group by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,id
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the ascending sort to a descending sort:

```
select t.* 
from (select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, id,
             row_number() over (partition by id ORDER BY id desc) as seqnum
------------------------------------------------------------^
      from table
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```